Is there any tool/website available by which I can generate VASP input files?
I am familiar with QE input files, but totally new in VASP. I know by using the quantum espresso input generator(https://www.materialscloud.org/work/tools/qeinputgenerator), we can use CIF file
to get quantum espresso input file easily. Likewise, Is there any tool available by which I can generate VASP input files?
Thanks!

Do you mean the structural information (lattice and atomic sites) or also all the simulation parameters?

VASPKIT

@PhilHasnip also all the simulation parameters,,,Would you please suggest something?

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine Thank you for your suggestion. I am starting to look for it.

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine Is it possible to prepare AIMD (VASP) input files using VASPKIT?

@Md.JahidHasanSagor I don't know that. According to the documentation, there is an option to customize your INCAR for Molecular Dynamics. Maybe try that. You can always ask a new question such as how to use vaspkit to generate AIMD input files. There are many VASP experts here. I am sure someone will respond.

There are lots of ways to get the structure (e.g. Vesta, or if you have a CIF cif2cell), but I'm not sure what the best options are for the parameters. ASE is the obvious one, and of course if you have inputs for QE you can just convert them: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/
